# Is there a better way to optimise the for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, v8, chakracore

I wrote

```
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
   for(var j=0;j< 10000;j++){
 }
```

}

Now this loop takes around 2603 ms in Chrome but takes around 60884 ms in Internet Explorer 11. I want to bring the second number somewhat closer or even remotely comparable to first one.

Now, is there a ChakraCore specific guideline or trick that can get it done faster?

Comment: well, here a faster option: `;` - an empty statement, which is strictly equivalent to your code above.

Comment: seriously, what is your actual question?

Comment: to get what done faster - it does nothing, how can you optimise no statements?

Comment: ahhh, now we see real code

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here... The thing is why two browsers have such a high difference? I tried using variable names but the performance doesn't seem to budge.

Comment: wrap it in an IIFE for 10x speed (this speeds up firefox as well)